# asp.net core Aurelia project in Typescript - parameter XXX implicitly has 'any' type error

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, aurelia

This is an error I am getting in Visual Studio 2017 and it should be OK however its failing in a number of places with this and I have done nothing to the code - got it off a template.

Here is one example:

```
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin('aurelia-api', config => {
        config.registerEndpoint('weather', 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts');

        if (IS_DEV_BUILD) {
            aurelia.use.developmentLogging();
        }

        new HttpClient().configure(config => {
            const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href;
            config.withBaseUrl(baseUrl);
        });

        aurelia
            .start()
            .then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app/app/app")));
    }
  }
```

In this case the error is on config (red squiggly line under it) with the error:

> Error TS7006  (TS) Parameter 'config' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here's another:

```
        import { inject } from "aurelia-framework";
        import {Rest} from 'aurelia-api';

        @inject(Rest)
        export class WeatherForcasts {
          constructor (restClient) {
            restClient.find('product', {
                category: 5,
                name    : {contains: 'mouse'}
              })
              .then(console.log)
              .catch(console.error);
          }
        }
```

The same error - this time the red line is under the "restClient" parameter:

> Error TS7006  (TS) Parameter 'restClient' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these errors because the type of your variables are not specified. Ideally you should add the type everywhere or explicitely specify `any`.

But you can also add this option in your **ts.config** file to avoid these errors:

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "noImplicitAny": false
}
```